# Unable to see Windows Phone 7.8 Emulators in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator, windows-phone-7-emulator, windows-phone-7.8

I've recently installed the Windows Phone 8.0 SDK and when developing a new Windows Phone HTML App, I can see a few emulators listed which when run, open up the emulator fine:

Emulator WVGA 512 MB
Emulator WVGA 
Emulator XVGA
Emulator 720P

To test for functionality on a different handset (Nokia Lumia 710), it looked like I needed to install the Windows Phone SDK update for Windows phone 7.8 which "Adds the ability to start a Windows Phone 7.8 emulator in Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012.".  I was expecting to see the new 7.8 emulators added to the list, but they are not being displayed.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?  Am I missing a further step?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only can see Windows Phone 7.8 emulators if your project is for Windows Phone 7.5

If your project has been updated or created for 8, you won't see them.

Comment: Great, thanks for your advice.  I was only creating a Windows Phone App in order to launch the emulator and test a site in IE on a particular version.  Initially, I was using the Windows Phone HTML app project type to try and achieve this.  If I create a Windows Phone App and set the target OS to 7.1, I do indeed see all the emulators listed, which when running allow me to test other sites using IE on the desired platform.